# Should I use Google In-app purchases or Google Pay for this case?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, applepay, google-pay

I am not sure if I have to use google in-app purchases or google pay for these use cases. Insight into this issue is appreciated. We are working on an application which has the following scenarios:

- Patients can search for, book an appointment with a doctor and pay for the service from the app. In this case, can I use Google Pay since the service rendered is physical and not a virtual service or good?
- A doctor can subscribe to or buy add ons in the app to customize their workflow. Since this is a virtual good/service I'm assuming I have to use google in-app purchasing.Right?

Would it be advisable to implement two payment processors for the respective features or do I have to go with only one of the payment processors? Would using only one lead to google blocking the app?
Any insight into such scenarios is appreciated.

Comment: You are correct. You need to use two different payment systems for the two different cases

Answer (score 0):

Further to what @Paulw11 said, the following answer explains it in more detail: [Google Play/App Store in-app purchase policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804299/google-play-app-store-in-app-purchase-policies/29804670#29804670)