# Is it possible to replace Google Play IAB with Google Pay?

Tags: android, google-play, google-pay

Google Play IAB charges 30% transaction fee while Google Pay is free for both business owners and customers. If we can use a WebView to show a Google Pay flow instead of using Google Play's billing, it will be enormous amount of revenue boost. We may still need Google Play to manage the subscriptions, but for one time purchases, it seems certainly replaceable.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are selling.

The following answer provides a very good overview: [Google Play/App Store in-app purchase policies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804299/google-play-app-store-in-app-purchase-policies/29804670#29804670)

> **In-app purchases:**
>
> - Developers offering virtual goods or currencies
>     within a game downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's
>     in-app billing service as the method of payment.
> - Developers offering additional content, services or functionality within another category of app downloaded from Google Play must use Google Play's in-app billing service as the method of payment, except:
>
>   - where payment is primarily for physical goods or services (e.g., buying movie tickets, or buying a publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription); or
>   - where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed outside of the app itself (e.g., buying songs that can be played on other music players).