# Use Google Play for billing or other system for mobile app

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, policies

I am developing a mobile app where users can create works of art for purchase. In order to download the completed art, the user must purchase the artwork. The artwork is then downloaded as a PNG to the user's device. The image can only be used outside the app. The downloaded artwork cannot be used inside the app. Should I use Google Play's billing system or my own (such as Stripe) for the purchase?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804670/2233706), I should not use in-app billing for my app because it's not allowed

> where payment is for digital content or goods that may be consumed
> outside of the app itself (e.g., buying songs that can be played on
> other music players).

However, I cannot find any reference to this in [Google's documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738?hl=en&ref_topic=9857752).

I chatted with their customer support, and they told me they can't help with me "technical support for app development questions" and should I refer to the documentation.

Comment: have you find a solution ?

Comment: I had submitted the app using Stripe for billing, and it was approved. I later changed to using in-app purchases because the rates were better, and they didn't complain either.